# Save Form as PDF/Email to User C#/ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, webforms

I don't really know where to start with this project. I've done a bit of research on here and haven't found exactly what I need. Essentially, I have a form that a user will navigate to, fill out several texts boxes/radio buttons. I have a submit button at the bottom that submits the data into my SQL database. I'm working in Visual Basic (C#/ASP).

After submission, I would like to include an option to save the webform as a PDF and an option, if possible, to email a copy of that webform to another user/group. I'm thinking the easiest way to do that would be to just include the save as pdf option and then the user can go to their personal email and do it that way.

Is there any basic "Save Webform as PDF" code template or any tips you all can give me? Feel free to post links to other questions/forums as I tried to read as much as I could over the past few days.

As always, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a page that shows how to create a PDF from textbox data using iTextSharp.

https://forums.asp.net/t/1906686.aspx?convert+aspx+page+into+pdf+and+send+the+pdf+as+attachment

This page shows how to send a PDF through email.

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/459105/Convert-web-page-to-pdf-and-send-it-as-attachment

Good Luck!

Comment: That did it! Downloaded iText, added the references, and got the converting to pdf portion down. Thanks again!

Comment: For new software development, do not use iText 5 (also known as iTextSharp). Use iText 7 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few .NET libraries that will convert HTML or WebPages to PDF

PDFSharp: http://www.pdfsharp.net/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
Free .NET PDF Library: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=E-iceblueCoLtd.FreeNETPDFLibrary
iText 7: https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet

You could produce a receipt page and then give the user the option to convert that page to pdf for their records using one of these libraries.

Comment: Please do not link to iText on Sourceforge. It is no longer maintained there. Go to https://github.com/itext